# MySQL Selecting rows with the latest available date with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table with a StormID column and ModelBaseTime column (and a few other columns)..

I'm trying to get all records and all fields where the StormID = 'AL012015' AND only those records with the latest ModelBaseTime for that particular StormID.

Here's what I've tried by researching on SO.

```
SELECT * FROM adeck_raw WHERE StormID = 'AL012015' 
AND ModelBaseTime IN(SELECT MAX(ModelBaseTime))
ORDER BY StormID;
```

^^ This returns way too many results with multiple ModelBaseTime instead of the latest only.

```
SELECT * FROM adeck_raw 
WHERE StormID = 'AL012015' AND ModelBaseTime IN
    (SELECT MAX(ModelBaseTime)
     FROM adeck_raw
     GROUP BY StormID
    )
GROUP BY StormID
ORDER BY ModelBaseTime;
```

^^This returns 1 record (I know there are multiple)

```
SELECT * adeck_raw AS t
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT StormID, MAX(ModelBaseTime) AS latest_date FROM adeck_raw WHERE StormdID = 'AL012015' GROUP BY StormID
) AS sq
USING (StormID, ModelBaseTime);
```

^^This does not execute... sql syntax error

```
SELECT*, MAX(ModelBaseTime)
FROM adeck_raw WHERE StormID = 'AL012015'
GROUP BY StormID;
```

^^ This only returns 1 record

Thanks for any suggestion and examples.
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM adeck_raw AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(ModelBaseTime) AS latest_date
   FROM adeck_raw
   WHERE StormID = 'AL012015'
) AS t2 ON t1.ModelBaseTime = t2.latest_date
WHERE StormID = 'AL012015';
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you for your help.